# word-tokenize column of dataframe of text type

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, feature-extraction

My Dataframe is as follows:

[image]

I want to use **word-tokenize** and extract **features** of sentence to **classify** them in different **categories**.

#### My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


cov = pd.read_csv("F:/kipro/ml/dataset.csv", 
              names = ["Complaint", "type"])
print(cov)
cov['tokenized_text'] = cov.apply(lambda 
              row:word_tokenize(cov['Complaint']), axis=1) 
print(cov['tokenized_text'])   
wd=[]
all_words=(list(cov['tokenied_text'])
for w in all_words:
    wd.append(w.lower())
wd=nltk.FreqDist(wd)
word_feature=(list(wd.keys()))[:3000]
def find_feature(cov):
    stmt=set(cov)
    features={}
    for w in word_feature:
        features[w]=w in words
    return features
std=cov.type.unique()
featureset=[(find_feature(cov.Complaint),std) for (Complaint,type) in cov]
```

But when I am using word tokenize I get following error at line

> cov['tokenized_text'] = cov.apply(lambda row: word_tokenize(cov['Complaint']), axis=1)
>
> for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
> TypeError: ('expected string or bytes-like object', 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0):

Change

`cov['tokenized_text'] = cov.apply(lambda 
              row:word_tokenize(cov['Complaint']), axis=1)`
to

```
cov['tokenized_text'] = cov.Complaint.apply(lambda row: word_tokenize(row))
```

Apply the operation on the series not to a dataframe.

```
>>> cov
                                           Complaint
0  The agent was not able to open because the bot...
1                                    Sample sentence
2  The agent was not able to open because the bot...
3  The agent was not able to open because the bot...
>>> cov['tokenized'] = cov.Complaint.apply(lambda x: word_tokenize(x))
>>> cov
                                           Complaint  \
0  The agent was not able to open because the bot...   
1                                    Sample sentence   
2  The agent was not able to open because the bot...   
3  The agent was not able to open because the bot...   

                                           tokenized  
0  [The, agent, was, not, able, to, open, because...  
1                              [Sample, sentence]  
2  [The, agent, was, not, able, to, open, because...  
3  [The, agent, was, not, able, to, open, because...  
>>>
```

If you want to use text features such as count, I would suggest going with **sklearn(CountVectorizer or TfIdfVectorizer)**

Comment: @radikk It should work. This give the tokens in the separate series with those elements as list of tokens. See the updated answer.